# Using New Relic with Meteor

Tags: meteor, newrelic

I am interested in incorporating New Relic's app monitoring capabilities in Meteor. Has anyone had experience using New Relic with Meteor and if so, how do you integrate the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The New Relic agent is on npm, though it's still in beta. I installed it in one of my deployed app by going into bundle/server and typing `npm install newrelic`, setting up the config file and adding `require('newrelic')` in server.js.

The agent is running and sending data to New Relic.

Two points, the first being the web transactions displayed are all the sockjs polling, so the while you do see response times and whatnot, with Meteor, the response times are not tied to particular transactions, thus limiting the usability.

The second is the agent did not track external service requests, of which my app makes a lot of. I have not had a chance to dig in and see why, but my takeaway is that New Relic is not particularly well suited to Meteor apps.

As a disclaimer, I should say that I did not read any New Relic documentation and this test was just a cursory setup to see if it work, so don't take my word on this. I'm writing this as a stepping stone for someone to do a more detailed inspection of integration.

Answer (score 5):

With the node.js agent being in beta, there's no specific instrumentation for Meteor.  This is why you don't see defined web transactions as "Meteor specific."

External service requests are also a work in progress and probably not going to behave the way you expect.

Comment: I'm looking forward to when more information is provided. Seeing what is going on server side is pretty opaque in Meteor right now.

Answer (score 1):

Because meteor is built off node you might have to just wait a short amount of time for them to release their npm module:

http://try.newrelic.com/nodejs